# Bash to Fish Conversion: Display custom message when CD'ing into a specific directory

Tags: shell-script, fish

Basically, I'd like to create a file .cd-reminder with an announcement/message inside a specific directory. It will be displayed every time someone 'cd' into that specific directory.

There is a shell script for that already and I'm currently using Fish and not familiar on how to convert it; any help appreciated!

```
reminder_cd() { 
    builtin cd "$@" && { [ ! -f .cd-reminder ] || cat .cd-reminder 1>&2; }
}

alias cd=reminder_cd`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function cd
    builtin cd $argv
    and test -f .cd-reminder
    and cat .cd-reminder
end
```

---

I just realized this will return a non-success exit status when the .cd-reminder file does not exist in a directory. use this instead so the function will only return non-success if you can't cd to the given dir.

```
function cd
    builtin cd $argv
    and begin
        test -f .cd-reminder
        and cat .cd-reminder
        or true
    end
end
```

Comment: Note that this overrides the built-in `cd` function, which means that directory history (`prevd` and `nextd`) won't work.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a function like this to your `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
function show-reminder --on-variable PWD
   if test -f .cd-reminder
        cat .cd-reminder
   end
end
```

(This avoids overriding the built-in `cd` function, which likes to keep directory history that you can use.)

Note that you should not add this as an autoloaded function in `~/.config/fish/functions/`, because it will not be picked up as triggering on the change of `$PWD` until it is run manually.

Comment: How do you do the same when you open a new tab with the directory set to that directory?

Comment: In that case, call the function straight away in your `config.fish`.